# Preventing an Ajax Form from sending "normally" wont work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a form using Ajax.
Therefore, thanks to stackoverflow, i am preventing the form from normally sending using `event.preventDefault();` but this will not help, because i am always getting redirected to my sendMail.php File.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.mailForm', function(e) {
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function()
        {
            $("#sendBox").show('slow');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Edit: Here is my form:

```
<form role="form" class="mailForm" action="sendmail.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fName" placeholder="<? LangText("Name", "Nom", "Name"); ?>" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="fMail" placeholder="<? LangText("E-Mail Adresse", "Adresse électronique", "email adress"); ?>" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fCompany" placeholder="<? LangText("Firma", "Entreprise", "Company"); ?>" required="required">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></div>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="fText" required="required"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitMail"><? LangText("Absenden", "Envoyer", "Send"); ?></button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Try $(".mailForm").on('submit',function(e){...

Comment: Do you get any Javascipt errors in your browser dev tool's console window?

Comment: If it's still redirecting to the action page, then there's an error in your JS. Check the console log on page load.

Comment: Can you edit your question and place the HTML of your form please?

Comment: Question is now edited.

Comment: I get one error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ), it says in line 234 but i only got 180.

Comment: Is it stating that the SyntaxError is on the form page, or another JS file?

Comment: I always do `$('body').on` for delegated events, are you sure the `$(document)` is fine? Does the event get fired If you console.log something inside your eventHandler, does it show up?

Comment: In the JavaScript you posted, I see two `{` back to back. Is that in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, seesms like the two `{` were causing the error, but that did not fix the problem. But Menno Gouw's answer did, so thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.mailForm', function(e) {
```

Try:

```
$(".mailForm").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function()
        {
            $("#sendBox").show('slow');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you. Cant Ajax handle forms with classes instead of ids or...?

Comment: Why would these options function differently? I mean, why would your suggestion work, and the OP's method not? `on('submit'...` catches the same event as `submit`, but only after it bubbles up the DOM to the document...

Comment: It can, i changed it. But why use classes? You have multiple forms of the same type?

Comment: @jwatts1980 good one, this is just how i remember doing it. I can recall having the same problems with preventDefault() and return false;. What if OP just leaves out preventDefault() and let return false handle it? No time for testing here.

Comment: @MennoGouw That is interesting... I will have to keep that in mind. To my knowledge I haven't run into a situation where I couldn't use ID's for the forms. So I always use `submit()`...

Comment: No, I am not really using multiple forms, seems like I forgot to use an id instead of a class ^^. Well, yes seems also like basically the same for me, but it works. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an event on form's 'Send' button.

```
            $('.trigger_buttton').on('click', function(e) {
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $('.mailForm').attr('action'),
                    type: $('.mailForm').attr('method'),
                    data: $('.mailForm').serialize(),
                    success: function()
                    {
                        $("#sendBox").show('slow');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: and what if a user hits 'enter' to submit?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, haven't seen that, I just submited my answer and closed my tab. It's the same rofl xD

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .submit() instead.

```
$(".mailForm").submit(function(e)
{

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function()
    {
        $("#sendBox").show('slow');
    }
  });
 return false;
});
```

Comment: You show awesome copy/paste skills :), iirc e.preventDefault() is not nececary since that is what return false does.

Comment: :) I was only concentrating on the .submit()